# GLSL code not rendering on NVIDIA via Cg compiler

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, nvidia

I am building a vision research experiment in Python and OpenGL. I am performing some displacement mapping of a texture. The GLSL code is version 330 compatible, and it renders perfectly on my machine. But when I run the code on the experiment desktop, I do not get anything, there are no logged messages or errors, it just renders a blank screen.

I ran the following on both machines:

```
print "OpenGL version:\t\t%s" % glGetString(GL_VERSION)
print "GLSL version:\t\t%s" % glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)
print "Vendor:\t\t\t%s" % glGetString(GL_VENDOR)
print "Renderer:\t\t%s" % glGetString(GL_RENDERER)
```

From my machine, I get the following output:

```
OpenGL version: 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2867
GLSL version: 4.00 - Build 9.17.10.2867
Vendor: Intel
Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
```

From the experiment desktop, I get the following:

```
OpenGL version: 3.3.0
GLSL version: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer: Quadro FX 3700/PCIe/SSE2
```

Here is an excerpt from the vertex and fragment shaders, is there something I am overlooking?

*vertex.shd:*

```
#version 330 compatibility

layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertVertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vertTexCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vertNormal;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

uniform sampler2D heightmap;

out vec4 fragVertex;
out vec2 fragTexCoord;

float convert_luminance(vec4 pixel) {
    return (0.2126 * pixel.r) + (0.7152 + pixel.g) + (0.0722 * pixel.b);
}

vec4 displacement_mapping(void) {
    // Get pixel values for TexCoord
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(heightmap, vertTexCoord.st);
    float grey_value = convert_luminance(pixel);

    // Return displaced position coordinates
    return vec4(vertNormal * grey_value, 0.0) + vec4(vertVertex, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void main(void) {
    fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord.st;
    fragVertex = displacement_mapping();

    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * (ModelViewMatrix * fragVertex);
}
```

*fragment.shd:*

```
#version 330 compatibility

in vec2 fragTexCoord;
in vec4 fragVertex;

uniform sampler2D colormap;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(colormap, fragTexCoord.st);
}
```

Comment: I would very much like to see your vertex array setup. Some less-than-compliant OpenGL implementations (usually from NVidia) will alias fixed-function vertex pointer calls (e.g. `glVertexPointer (...)` and `glTexCoordPointer (...)`) to explicit vertex attrib slots (even though they're not supposed to for anything other than vertex pointer = 0). A lot of times people grow accustomed to this behavior and then when it comes time to run the same code on a more standards-compliant driver the issue finally shows up. This is just speculation until I see more code, such as uniform and vtx. array setup